How to not display the loading icon when overlayNoRowsTemplate is displayed
Following is the code to display data in ag-grid when page loads.
components: {
        loadingCellRenderer: function (params) {
          if (params.node.id !== undefined ) {
            return params.value;
          } else {
            return `<img src=${loading}>`;
          }
        }
      }

When no rows fetched from backend then overlayNoRowsTemplate gets displayed.
fetchCall.fetchResponse().then(async response => {
          let endRow = -1;
          if (response.length) {
            if (response.length < pagination.pageSize) {
              endRow = params.startRow + response.length;
            }
            params.successCallback(response, endRow);
            this.gridApiVal.hideOverlay();
          } else {
            this.gridApiVal.showNoRowsOverlay();
          }
        });
      }

overlayNoRowsTemplate:
'No Rows in search result',
Issue in addition to overlayNoRowsTemplate ,loading icon  is displayed in the cell.
Requirement : loading icon  not to be shown after overlayNoRowsTemplate is displayed
